# "like a German engine" vs. "German engine like": which sounds better at the end of a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

If someone says that you are "quick" or "efficient" and you want to answer with the following concept "comparison with German engines", what is the best way of replying between this two options:

a) like a German engine

b) German engine like

Are both correct? What are the differences between these two sentences for native speakers?

Comment: Both are fine, but (b) should have hyphens to say someone is *german-engine-like*.

Comment: I personally think that B takes more of a cognitive load than A and the person might just sheepishly smile until they understand your semantics; if ever.

Comment: In spoken English, I only say (b) if I'm talking before even realizing what I want to say. The word "like" is an afterthought.

Comment: Avoid (b) as one would avoid a leper with cholera - it sounds awful.

Comment: Though b) -might- be used in very informal speech, it is very informal and would  be judged badly by any editor/school teacher.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct response would be Response *A*. In Response *B*, you may hyphenate *engine* and *like*. The sentence would be like this:
*It is German engine-like.*

However, this makes engine into an adjective; this changes the meaning of the sentence somewhat. The sentence connotation is now that it has similar *characteristics* to a German engine. Sentence *A* dictates that whatever you are talking about has the same process as a German engine (therefore, it is likely an engine as well).

This response is used more commonly in speech; Response *B* is a rather cumbersome way of saying it. I would avoid it entirely.

Anyways, *like* goes somewhere between the Predicate Adjective and the compared noun. For example:

1.) I am *fast* *like* a *cheetah*.

In the above example, *fast* (predicate adjective) and *cheetah* (compared noun) are the connected words. This sentence therefore gives the idea to the reader that I run at the *same speed* as a cheetah. This sentence is obviously false, and it is what we call *figurative language*. Another way of saying Sentence 1 is this:
1.) I am as fast as a cheetah.

*Like* compares two words. Here are some more examples:

2.) You are cool like me. (This means that I am cool, and you are cool)

3.) He is sitting like me. (This means that he is sitting in the *same fashion* as me)

4.) I am screaming like a girl.  (This means that my scream is *the same* as a girl's scream)

Let me know if you have any questions!
(By the way, I am not a native English speaker either; I am German, so I know that you can understand all of this!)

Comment: Approved the answer from @WS2 since he said that hypens are required, that is reasonable to give correctness to answer B, thanks.

Comment: @AlejandroMorán Edited.

Comment: On the other hand, "I am cheetah-like" wouldn't be toooooo bad. The big problem with "German-engine-like" is that it's so long and clunky. Exactly unlike a German engine! \*baddum-tsh\*

Comment: Sentence 4 is quite cisnormative, might I add.

Answer (score 4):

The first is an adverbial phrase qualifying an action  e.g. *It ran like a German engine*. But b) is adjectival (which in pre-position would require hyphens) e.g. *One noted the German-engine-like capability of the equipment.*

So the answer to your question is that **option a is the correct one**.

Your reply is short for ***Yes, I am quick like a German engine***.

Answer (score 1):

"Like a German engine" Is correct as is. Answer B would need hyphens
("German-engine-like") to be correct, but in conversation, as @Greybeard says, it sounds very odd.

```
                        Hope this helps!
```